# How to handle PySpark UDF return values in different types?

Tags: list, dataframe, pyspark, typeerror, user-defined-functions

I have a data frame with one column. In each row of this data frame, there is a list. For example :

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
        [[13,23]],
        [[55,65]],
    ],
    ['col',]
)
```

Then I defined a UDF which basically adds 1 to first number in the list and add 1.5 to the second number of the list.

```
def calculate(mylist) :
  x = mylist[0] + 1
  y = mylist[1] + 1.5
  return x,y
```

The problem is that when I apply this function to my data frame it returns the X value but it does not return the Y value.
I think it is because the Y value is not an integer.
This is the way that I do this.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType, ArrayType
func = F.udf(lambda x: calculate(x), ArrayType(IntegerType()))
df.withColumn('vals', func('col')).show()
```

What can I do to get the Y value as well as X value? I simplified the UDF and sample data frame for the sake of being easy to understand and solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

calculate `udf` is returning `integer` and also `float` type with the given input.
If your use case first value is integer and second value is `float`, you can return `StructType`

If both need to be same type, you can use the same code and change calculate `udf` which returns both integers

```
func = F.udf(lambda x: calculate(x), T.StructType(
        [T.StructField("val1", T.IntegerType(), True),
         T.StructField("val2", T.FloatType(), True)]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Now would you please help me to have X and Y in 2 columns separately? I am using this code           df = df.select("col", df.vals[0], df.vals[1])          but I am getting this error        
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Field name should be String Literal, but it&#39;s 0;

Comment: With your code, I am getting X and Y value in a list in 1 column. But I want to make X in one column and Y in another column, please.

Comment: @OMIDDavami Use the schema to decode, for example, use df.vals['val1'] instead of df.vals[0]